# Why is addrinfo loop needed?

Tags: ipv6, getaddrinfo

Suppose we have a pure IPv6 network.
A socket app uses getaddrinfo to find HOST1 by its hostname, and gets one of HOST1's IP addresses as the first response.
Why should it loop on the returned addresses? Isn't it the responsibilty of the routers or
HOST1's TCP/IP stack or the local TCP/IP stack to find an alternate route to HOST1, perhaps through a different network interface on HOST1?

You would think that finding routes to a host known by its name is a most basic functionality of a computer network infrastructure rather than the socket app.

Answer (score 3):

getaddrinfo() can give you addresses for a name that's really a different host, so you can still access the service if one host is down.

But the internet is quite dumb, it's not an intelligent network as they tried in the old telecom networks. The internet pushes functionality to the edges, and routers just look at IP addresses in a packet and sends out the best pipe it can.  That will indeed take care of issues where one path to that IP address is broken, the router will send the packet on an alternative path.

But the edge, your socket application, is responsible for deciding which IP address you want to send packets to, and whether you figure out which IP address to send packets to, by the means of querying DNS, LDAP, statically configuring, config files or what not, is no concern of the network.

You'd want to loop around on the getaddrinfo() results because resolving a name can give you different IP addresses, belonging to different hosts around the world that provides the same service, and can be reached over IPv4 or IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

No, the most basic functionality is to forward packets to their destination hosts. The internet design aims to let routers focus on the most basic functionality, and make the endpoints do as much as possible of the rest.

So, can and should *this* bit be left to the endpoints? I think yes, since it's no extra work for the endpoints, and would be considerable extra work for the routers.

The endpoints need code to try several addresses anyway, to support v4 and v6. And the routers would have to keep track of which sets of addresses comprise a host (whatever "host" means).

Answer (score 0):

Name resolution belongs to a different layer than routing. In technical terms, your question assumes that routers are application layer gateways which would be inefficient. You'd better start with some literature that gives you an overview on TCP/IP networking.